# Firefox Fullscreen Video Lag

Tags: nvidia, firefox, 18.04, fullscreen

Since I came to Ubuntu I have been facing a problem with full screen videos in Firefox. It looks like the display is synchronized with my graphics card.
The strangest is that out of full screen the problem does not occur.
(I have an Nvidia 1050 GPU, if it helps)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the monitor refresh rate. With me it happened in any video, that was in the browser or Totem, VLC etc. Under Settings go to Devices > Monitors > Resolution. click to change. At this point there is the resolution chosen by the system and just below the same resolution. choose the second option and the Update Rate will appear. Choose the one from your monitor if not already ... 60Hz, 120Hz etc. Do the test.